# MySQL table doesn't exists after copying files

Tags: mysql, linux

I have copied my database folder from windows system `C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql.XX/data/database_name` to a linux system `/var/lib/mysql/database_name`

I have connected to mysql through terminal , executed query `show tables;` it showing all the tebles in the database, but when I execute `select * from table_name` or `desc table_name` it showing error `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'database_name.table_name' doesn't exist`.

Any one have idea about it ?

Comment: The files should be compatible between systems but Linux is case sensitive but Windows isn't.

Comment: all the files are named with small letters;

Comment: MysqlDB format may vary from windows to linux , so add the property as `lower_case_table_names=0` at /etc/my.conf in linux system so it will enable accept your queries normally.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, solved by copying **ibdata1** from backup to **/var/lib/mysql**.

I was trying to recover whole database, don't know what will happen with just one table.

Comment: My workaround was just substitute the original file with the backed one for short time, running mysqladmin, dumping the tables I needed and then restored original file again. (Remember to back it up before overwritting it)

Comment: This worked, Note I used the exact same version of MySQL on each server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqldump` to copy database, **do not copy binary data file**.

When you manual copy binary file, some internal data can be inconsistent, for example, some transaction can be not finished.

Also if you move data file to different mysql version/storage engine version, engine may not be able read file in new/previous version format.

Also system encoding may be different, so internal data representation may be different and completly incompatible on Windows and Linux.

Comment: thats not anwer answer ,, in case my mysql server got crashed.. I got only files, how can i ???

Comment: If your server got crashed, in what i don't belive at all, set up _exactly the same_ server version with _exactly the same_ storage engine on _exactly the same OS_ and do `mysqlcheck` commant. Don't move binary data on different OS and ask why it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems a bit unfair to @user1516873 for that answer, he's provided a suitable alternative approach and you'd not mentioned anything about the original host being unrecoverable in your OP. Build a VM and use mysqldump.